# Execute template to file

Tags: go

I have a template file `template.html` as follow

```
Hello {{.Name}}, welcome!
```

and the code

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "text/template"
)
func main() {
  type person struct {
    Name string
  }

  p := &person{"clinyong"}
  t := template.Must(template.New("template.html").ParseFiles("template.html"))
  f, err := os.OpenFile("test", os.O_CREATE, 0777)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
  }
  defer f.Close()

  err := t.Execute(f, p)
  if err != nil {
      fmt.Println(err)
  }
}
```

`t.Execute(f, p)` calls a error, saying that f is a bad file descriptor.

Is it possible to execute a template output to a file as shown above? I see some examples, the `f` in `Execute` is almost http.ResponseWriter or os.Stdout.

Comment: You're omitting the error returned by `os.OpenFile`, check it (!!!) I presume that it's not nil.

Comment: The error is nil here...

Comment: Okay, then you're doing it correctly, hmm. Can you please post the exact error string that you get?

Comment: You did not open `f` with the correct permissions; you need to include the flag `os.O_WRONLY` or `os.O_RDWR`.

Comment: or if you don't need special flags or permissions just use `os.Create`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @TimCooper said, I need to include `os.O_WRONLY` in `os.OpenFile`.